# Tetris trouble bug-fixing

Tags: python, tetris

I have just started learning pygame and wanted to begin with Tetris. I chose TechwithTim's tutorial to start with
[Link to github](https://github.com/techwithtim/Tetris-Game)

My 2 problem that I encounter are with

```
def clear_rows(grid, locked):
    # need to see if row is clear the shift every other row above down one

    inc = 0
    for i in range(len(grid)-1,-1,-1):
        row = grid[i]
        if (0, 0, 0) not in row:
            inc += 1
            # add positions to remove from locked
            ind = i
            for j in range(len(row)):
                try:
                    del locked[(j, i)]
                except:
                    continue
    if inc > 0:
        for key in sorted(list(locked), key=lambda x: x[1])[::-1]:
            x, y = key
            if y < ind:
                newKey = (x, y + inc)
                locked[newKey] = locked.pop(key)


   return inc
```

If you fill 3 lines but there is one in the middle that is not complete in between those two, then the grid doesn't go down correctly,

[image: Bug1]

Secondly:

```
def check_lost(positions):
    for pos in positions:
        x, y = pos
        if y < 1:
            return True
    return False
```

If The player rotate the shape above the grid the game automatic count that as a lost

[image: Bug2]

Anyone have any idea on how to fix these bug? I have looked for solutions in the comments on the youtube tutorial and similar code on github but they never fix any of these

Comment: I think this `locked_positions` (sometimes `locked`) magic is just bad design. Normally a Tetris implementation would work with the array which is called `grid` here. Also, if a tutorial doesn't work out of the box, that's also suspicious, could be a "sign". You may want to check out a different one.

Comment: I have to agree with tevemadar, and also, being out of bounds is not a loss condition on the actual game as it's not possible.